# Cannot access Internet from VLANs on an HP layer 2 and layer 3 switch

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, layer3, hp

I have got an HP switch, layer 2 and layer 3 capable. I created some VLANs. I have an ADSL router on VLAN 1 with the IP address `192.168.1.2`. From VLAN 1, I can access Internet, but from the other VLANs, I cannot access Internet. From the other VLANs I can access other VLANs.

Here is the switch configuration:

```
******************************************************************************
* Copyright (c) 2010-2016 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP          *
* Without the owner's prior written consent,                                 *
* no decompiling or reverse-engineering shall be allowed.                    *
******************************************************************************


Login authentication


Password:
<Switch>dis cu
#
 version 5.20.99, Release 2222P01
#
 sysname Switch
#
 clock timezone Italy add 01:00:00
 clock summer-time Italy repeating 02:00:00 2017 March last Sunday 03:00:00 2017 October last Sunday  01:00:00
#
 dhcp relay server-group 1 ip 192.168.1.1
#
 irf mac-address persistent timer
 irf auto-update enable
 undo irf link-delay
#
 domain default enable system
#
 dns resolve
 dns server 8.8.8.8
 dns server 8.8.4.4
 dns server 192.168.1.2
#
 telnet server enable
#
 lldp compliance cdp
#
 password-recovery enable
#
vlan 1
 description Base
#
vlan 20
 description Windows XP
#
vlan 100
 description Periferiche
#
vlan 182
 description PC
#
vlan 840
 description Wi-Fi
#
domain system
 access-limit disable
 state active
 idle-cut disable
 self-service-url disable
#
dhcp server ip-pool nome
 network 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 gateway-list 192.168.1.1
 dns-list 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 192.168.1.2
#
dhcp server ip-pool pc
 network 192.168.182.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 gateway-list 192.168.182.1
 dns-list 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 192.168.1.2
#
dhcp server ip-pool periferiche
 network 192.168.100.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 gateway-list 192.168.100.1
 dns-list 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 192.168.1.2
#
dhcp server ip-pool wifi
 network 192.168.200.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 gateway-list 192.168.200.1
 dns-list 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 192.168.1.2
#
dhcp server ip-pool xp
 network 192.168.20.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 gateway-list 192.168.20.1
 dns-list 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 192.168.1.2
#
user-group system
 group-attribute allow-guest
#
local-user XXXXX
 password cipher XXXXXX
 authorization-attribute level 3
 service-type ssh telnet
 service-type web
#
interface NULL0
#
interface Vlan-interface1
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
#
interface Vlan-interface20
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
 dhcp select relay
 dhcp relay server-select 1
#
interface Vlan-interface100
 ip address 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0
 dhcp select relay
 dhcp relay server-select 1
#
interface Vlan-interface182
 ip address 192.168.182.1 255.255.255.0
 dhcp select relay
 dhcp relay server-select 1
#
interface Vlan-interface840
 ip address 192.168.200.1 255.255.255.0
 dhcp select relay
 dhcp relay server-select 1
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 description Stampante Lexmark
 port access vlan 100
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
 description Stampante LBP5050N
 port access vlan 100
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
 description NAS (Network Attached Storage)
 port access vlan 100
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14
 port access vlan 100
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
 port access vlan 840
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
 port access vlan 182
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22
 description PC Windows XP
 port access vlan 20
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
 description Modem e access point
 lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/25
 shutdown
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/26
 shutdown
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/27
 shutdown
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/28
 shutdown
#
 ip route-static 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.2 preference 65
#
 dhcp server forbidden-ip 192.168.1.0 192.168.1.2
#
 dhcp enable
#
 ntp-service unicast-server 193.204.114.232
 ntp-service unicast-server 193.204.114.233
#
 ssh server enable
#
 load xml-configuration
#
user-interface aux 0
user-interface vty 0
 user privilege level 3
 set authentication password cipher XXXXXX
user-interface vty 1 15
#
return
<Switch>
```

How could I solve my issue?

One strange thing that I noticed on the ADSL router is that it has got a WAN IP 79.35.XXX.XXX and gateway 192.168.100.1 (why?); but I cannot modify that. The ADSL router is provided by the phone company and it has got limited configuration possibilities.

```
<Switch>display ip routing-table
Routing Tables: Public
    Destinations : 10       Routes : 10

Destination/Mask    Proto  Pre  Cost         NextHop         Interface

0.0.0.0/0           Static 65   0            192.168.1.2     Vlan1  
127.0.0.0/8         Direct 0    0            127.0.0.1       InLoop0  
127.0.0.1/32        Direct 0    0            127.0.0.1       InLoop0  
192.168.1.0/24      Direct 0    0            192.168.1.1     Vlan1  
192.168.1.1/32      Direct 0    0            127.0.0.1       InLoop0  
192.168.20.0/24     Direct 0    0            192.168.20.1    Vlan20  
192.168.20.1/32     Direct 0    0            127.0.0.1       InLoop0  
192.168.100.0/24    Direct 0    0            192.168.100.1   Vlan100  
192.168.100.1/32    Direct 0    0            127.0.0.1       InLoop0
```

I cannot ping the ADSL router at its IP address, 192.168.1.2, from VLANs other than VLAN1.

Comment: What is the router model and configuration? How are you telling it about all the networks connected to the switch?

Comment: can you post current forwarding table and VLANS

Comment: You really need to provide the information we have requested. You have not provided enough information to answer your question.

Comment: One strange thing that I noticed on the ADSL router is that it has got a WAN IP 79.35.XXX.XXX and gateway 192.168.100.1 (why?); but I cannot modify that. The ADSL router is provided by the phone company and it has got limited configuration possibilities.

Comment: Is that the table you asked for?

Comment: That's the switch's routing table. The Internet router needs a backroute for 192.168.0.0/16 to 192.168.1.1 Addiitionally, the switch isn't routing currently.

Comment: What is the router model and configuration? How are you telling it about all the networks connected to the switch?

Comment: The router is a Technicolor DGA 4130. I did not know I had to configure it too. I do not find the possibility to add routes in its configuration menu, that I think is customized for the phone company that provide it.

Comment: No, the switch is routing, the switch routing table is the proof that the switch is routing. That is the way to configure an HP switch to route.

Comment: HP ProVision L3 switches require an `ip routing` to turn on routing. _Every_ device has a routing table.

Comment: My switch does not have the ip routing command, that is a Cisco command; but I would appreciate to know how to do, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately my switch does not have the NAT feature. If I buy the HP J9775A router (https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4AA5-4569ENW&doctype=data%20sheet&doclang=EN_US&searchquery=&cc=uk&lc=en) could I configure the NAT or the PAT so that it converts all the VLAN addresses to addresses in the same VLAN of my VDSL modem/router?

Comment: @Dfhke If your HP switch does not support routing, you cannot accomplish what you are  trying to do. You will need a router, as Zac67 has already pointed out.

Comment: Or perhaps adding the router I spoke about above I could just put my VDSL modem/router on his own VLAN and that would solve my issue.

Comment: @Cown My switch does support routing, it just does not need the ip routing command to start routing. My switch does not have Cisco operating system, it has got H3C Comware operating system.

Comment: @Dfhke the command is the same as Cisco. In config mode, you just write `IP ROUTING`

Comment: @Cown The command "ip routing" does not exist in H3C Comware. Anyway I have just ordered the HP J9775A router.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the HP R110 WW (J9975A) router NAT feature to connect my network to my phone company modem/router solved the issue. Thank you